# How to send a JavaScript function to C++, and call it later

Tags: javascript, qtwebkit

I need to reimplement a JavaScript framework using QWebKit. Currently I've been successful in calling C++ methods from JavaScript, but now I need to register a JavaScript callback, and be able to call it from C++.

In the original system (made using WebkitGTK), I built a C function which received an object as parameter. That object was the JavaScript function to be called as callback. An example:

```
bool cb_function(param1, param2) {

   alert("This is the callback, called with "+param1);

}

my_c_class.set_callback(cb_function);
```

Here, I define the *cb_function* callback, and send it to the underlying framework. Then, in C, I used JSObjectCallAsFunction() to call the JavaScript function whenever I needed, sending to it some parameters.

What I need to know is how to do this with QtWebKit instead. I presume that the first part needs to use a Q_INVOKABLE method (called, in this case, *set_callback*) which receives a QObject or QVariant parameter. Is this right?

And now the second part: how can I call from C++ that function stored in that QObject or QVariant?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't *really* pass the function to C++, and you can't *directly* call a JavaScript function from C++. However, what you want is achievable in a couple of ways:

One thing you can do is "connect" a JS function to one of a QObject's signals, (effectively making it a slot - if you're used to the Qt signal/slot terminology) and then emit that signal from C++ which will trigger (effectively "call") the JS function - and optionally pass it values as arguments.

The other (less awesome) way is to use the QWebFrame's "evaluateJavaScript" method to evaluate a string that call the function from the JS context - provided it's a function in the global scope, and you know the name of it. Presumably you could pass its name to a C++ method like the "set_callback" you describe, then pass that string to the evaluate method I mentioned earlier.